# Dygraphs how to implement two labels for one axis

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have a Dygraphs graph with one data series. The particularity is I would like to implement two y labels for this series. A percentage on the left y axis and a value on the right y axis.

I tried to implement two data series (one for the percentage and one for the value). But I can't figure out how to avoid the drawing of the second series.

Here are my current options :

```
this.options = {
  width: 700, height: 300, labels: ['Time', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
  ylabel: 'Coupled Power [%]',
  y2label: 'Signal Value [µW]',
  series: {
    'Y1': {axis: 'y1'},
    'Y2': {axis: 'y2'}
    },
};
```

Here is an example of what I expect :

[image]

My question is how can I avoid the drawing of the Y2 serie, or if I can't, how can I have two y labels for one data serie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution myself. So, like in the example I added two data series :

- One called Y1 for the left axe and which contains my percentage
- An other one called Y2 for the right axe and which contains my corresponding value

Then I had to avoid the drawing of Y2 (Y1 and Y2 were overlaping and were causing performance issues).

To do that I set the strokeWidth of Y2 to 0 and I disabled Y2 points higlighting with "drawHighlightPointCallback".

Here are my finals options :

```
this.options = {
  width: 700, height: 300, labels: ['Time', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
  ylabel: 'Coupled Power [%]',
  y2label: 'Signal Value [µW]',
  series: {
    'Y1': {
      axis: 'y1'
    },
    'Y2': {
      axis: 'y2',
      strokeWidth: 0,
      pointSize: 0,
      drawHighlightPointCallback: function (g, seriesName, canvasContext, cx, cy, color, pointSize) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

I hope this will help you !

Answer (score 0):

The labels of the graph are placed absolute inside the `div` with the graph. The graph is drawn on a `canvas`.

With jQuery or plain javascript DOM queries locate the child divs with the following class

```
<div class="dygraph-axis-label dygraph-axis-label-y">000</div>
```

Get the parent and determine if the text is aligned left: `text-align: left;` or if the `left` position is > width*0.5.

```
<div style="position: absolute; font-size: 14px; width: 50px; top: 242.259px; left: 500px; text-align: left;">
    <div class="dygraph-axis-label dygraph-axis-label-y">000</div>
</div>
```

Keep a list of these parent divs and when all are collected. Remove them from the DOM. Maybe you can remove it directly but this is the safe method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the entire secondary y-axis (label and ticks), you can use the [`drawAxis`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#drawAxis) option:

```
const options = {
  width: 700, height: 300, labels: ['Time', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
  ylabel: 'Coupled Power [%]',
  // y2label: 'Signal Value [µW]',
  series: {
    'Y1': {axis: 'y1'},
    'Y2': {axis: 'y2'}
  },
  axes: {
    y2: {
      drawAxis: false  // <---
    }
  }
};
```

If you just want to hide the label, you can either not set `y2label` or you can use CSS to hide it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but none of your solutions are working for me. I want to avoid the drawing of the Y2 serie, and not to hide the labels. I edited my question it was maybe unclear

Comment: Ok I finally found a solution, I posted it so you can probably implement a more convenient way to achieve this on Dygraphs :)